# Why no zoom dropdown in ASP.NET reportviewer in Firefox?

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010. The web reportviewer is not showing the zoom dropdown in the report toolbar in Firefox. It shows in IE & Chrome. I have ShowZoomControl true. Is this a limitation of the control? Why?

Answer (score 2):

it seems zooming is only supported in IE, please see it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251670.aspx

and there's a section about zoom saying that:

> Zooming the Report Page
>
> The ReportViewer toolbar provides standard zoom functionality so that
>   you can enlarge or shrink the report. The Web server control only
>   provides zooming support in Internet Explorer.